# Correct SQL syntax in this case

Tags: c#, sql

I have this Table Main:

```
"Record ID",Status,Placement,Private,Category,Note,Description,"Due Date",Completed,Priority,Blob,"Repeat On Complete Date","Complete Date","Alarm Set","Alarm Time","Alarm Advance","Repeat Start Date","Repeat Info"
```

An example entry

```
14340973,132,2147483647,False,3,Any note,Any Description,1956556799,False,1,System.Byte[],False,1956556799,False,1956470400,0,0,
```

What would the correct syntax for an Insert into in SQL be?

This is what I did:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Main ( Record ID , Status , Placement , Private , Category , Note , Description , Due Date , Completed , Priority , Blob , Repeat On Complete Date , Complete Date , Alarm Set , Alarm Time , Alarm Advance , Repeat Start Date , Repeat Info ) VALUES (@Rid,132, 2147483647, False,, @Kat, @Not, @Bes, 1956556799, False, @Pri, '', 1956556799, False, 1956470400, 0, 0, '', '')"; 
        MessageBox.Show(strSQL);
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, AufgabenVerbindung);
        }
        catch (Exception vvxc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(vvxc.Message);
        }
        OleDbParameter Kat, Not, Bes, Pri, Rid;
        Rid = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rid", OleDbType.BigInt);
        Kat = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Kat", OleDbType.TinyInt);
        Not = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Not", OleDbType.VarChar);
        Bes = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bes", OleDbType.VarChar);
        Pri = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pri", OleDbType.TinyInt);
        Rid.Value = Record_ID + 1;
        Kat.Value = 5;
        Not.Value = txtNotiz.Text;
        Bes.Value = txtBeschreibung.Text;
        Pri.Value = pri;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() throws the exception

Current Code: http://pastebin.com/16FwUhLr

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If so, show us and tell us what's not working.

Comment: string strSQL = "INSERT INTO `Main` ( `Record ID` , `Status` , `Placement` , `Private` , `Category` , `Note` , `Description` , `Due Date` , `Completed` , `Priority` , `Blob` , `Repeat On Complete Date` , `Complete Date` , `Alarm Set` , `Alarm Time` , `Alarm Advance` , `Repeat Start Date` , `Repeat Info` ) VALUES (@Rid,132, 2147483647, False,, @Kat, @Not, @Bes, 1956556799, False, @Pri, '', 1956556799, False, 1956470400, 0, 0, '', '')";

Comment: It's a bad idea to go from where I left as finding the error there is harder than giving a solution. Especially the Blob is what is hard to understand.

Comment: brackets, like this "[Record ID]"

Comment: Either brackets (T-SQL) or quotes (MySQL, PostgreSQL) depending on your DBMS.

Comment: The code: http://pastebin.com/16FwUhLr

Answer (score 6):

I see two problems.  First you have column names with spaces, if this is for SQL Server try wraping them in `[]` like below:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Main ( [Record ID] , Status , Placement , Private , Category , Note , Description , [Due Date] , Completed , Priority , Blob , [Repeat On Complete Date] , [Complete Date] , [Alarm Set] , [Alarm Time] , [Alarm Advance] , [Repeat Start Date] , [Repeat Info] ) VALUES (@Rid,132, 2147483647, False,, @Kat, @Not, @Bes, 1956556799, False, @Pri, '', 1956556799, False, 1956470400, 0, 0, '', '')";
```

If this is MySQL I believe you need to wrape the column names with `

**Also** this portion: `False,, @Kat,`  is invalid.  Try removing the extra comma or putting a value in there.

Comment: Good catch on that second one

Comment: even False,'',@Kat, does not change anything

Comment: I mentioned two errors, did you fix both?  What type of database is this for?

Comment: You appear to be inserting 19 values into 18 columns.  I would guess you need to change `False,'',@Kat` to `False,@Kat`

Comment: Now my insert into looks like this: INSERT INTO Main ( [Record ID], Status , Placement , Private , Category , [Note] , Description , [Due Date] , Completed , Priority , Blob , [Repeat On Complete Date] , [Complete Date] , [Alarm Set] , [Alarm Time] , [Alarm Advance] , [Repeat Start Date] , [Repeat Info] ) VALUES (14346099,132, 2147483647, False,5, 'MietenMieten', 'Mieten', 1956556799, False, 3, '', 1956556799, False, 1956470400, 0, 0, '', '') which leads to an overflow at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 3):

Wrap with `[]` those fields containing white spaces

For instance

`[Record ID]` and `[Due Date]`

Comment: @Carl Kunschel - What is the exact text of the exception?

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntaxfehler in der INSERT INTO-Anweisung

Comment: Now my insert into looks like this: INSERT INTO Main ( [Record ID], Status , Placement , Private , Category , [Note] , Description , [Due Date] , Completed , Priority , Blob , [Repeat On Complete Date] , [Complete Date] , [Alarm Set] , [Alarm Time] , [Alarm Advance] , [Repeat Start Date] , [Repeat Info] ) VALUES (14346099,132, 2147483647, False,5, 'MietenMieten', 'Mieten', 1956556799, False, 3, '', 1956556799, False, 1956470400, 0, 0, '', '') which leads to an overflow at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()